# how to use Directus with gatsby

Tags: php, jsx, gatsby, directus

How is it possible to use the Directus data in getsby.js

I've setup a Directus app, and added tables and data/columns but I have no clue how to use it in gatsby.js, I have build a template like this in jsx:

```
const path = require('path')

exports.createPages = ({ boundActionCreators, graphql }, { urlPrefix }) => {
 const { createPage } = boundActionCreators

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
resolve(
  graphql(
    `
      {
        allDirectusPost {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              title
              author
              content
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  ).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      console.error('GraphQL query returned errors')
      reject(result.errors)
    }

    result.data.allDirectusPost.edges.forEach(edge => {
      try {
        let node = edge.node
        let path = `posts/${node.id}`
        createPage({
          path,
          layout: 'index',
          component: path.resolve('src/templates/post.jsx'),
          context: {
            post: node,
          },
        })
        console.log(`Generated page '${path}'`)
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to generate page posts/'${path}': ${error}`)
      }
    })
  })
)
})
}
```

and I have a homepage static site in gatsby.js like this

```
import React from 'react'
import Link from 'gatsby-link'
// import postsTemplate from '../templates/post.jsx'

const IndexPage = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.000</p>
    <p>Now go build something great.</p>
    <post />
    <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link>
  </div>
)

export default IndexPage
```

how do I call the directus data in that gatsby file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each item in your Directus table, a new page will be created based off the `src/templates/post.jsx` component. This will be a completely separate set of pages to the `IndexPage`.

The steps to source pages from Directus is very similar to the steps to source pages from Markdown. I recommend you read https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/ one more time (though it looks like you did read it, since your `gatsby-node.js` code looks like it was borrowed from there). In `posts.jsx`, instead of querying `markdownRemark(frontmatter: { path: { eq: $path } })` you want to query `allDirectusPost(edges: { node: {id: {eq: $path } } })`.